# want to acess api generated by hyperledger-composer publicy not on localhost

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, blockchain.info-api

i have installed all the prerequisite needed for the development of hyper-ledger-fabric and hyper-ledger-composer i have successfully deployed the business-network IE .bna file on the fabric and i have also generated the rest-API for the composer but composer is running REST-API on local-host and i just want to access   it through any machine or i say i want to deploy my API so what should i do ?? should i use IBM blue mix or AWS?? and what the way to deploy it please "A detailed answer will be highly helpful"
THANKS..

Answer (score 2):

see the link below about deploying a Composer REST server for a deployed business network, and how to configure it so that it can connect to the running Fabric environment. There's also an example at the bottom showing how you can use Docker to create a persistent (and secured) REST server using Docker. No reason why you can't run your REST server / Fabric in the cloud.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

Comment: Thanks Paul !! you made it very clear to me i also want o ask that ehat the difference if i use composer network deploy command and if i use composer identity import command i am attaching the link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/bnd-deploy.html plz if u can help what the difference in deploying with those commands or are they same

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix has a Hyperledger service called "Blockchain" you can simply deploy if you want a simple solution that doesn't require in-depth knowledge of networking, docker hyperledger config and so on... 
https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south&taxonomyNavigation=apps

Comment: Thanks !! you made it very clear to me i also want o ask that ehat the difference if i use composer network deploy command and if i use composer identity import command i am attaching the link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/bnd-deploy.html plz if u can help what the difference in deploying with those commands or are they same

Answer (score 0):

You dont have full control on rest-apis generated by composer command.Also you need to implement own web api server to consume those apis and then pass those apis to your client app.
To solve this problem you can develop own api using node sdk. You can call logic.js functions through nodejs sdk.